# Error @types/signalr/index.d.ts is no ta module

Tags: signalr, typescript-typings, signalr-2

I'm trying to use signalr with Typescript. Server side is ASP.NET (not ASP.NET CORE) I installed both signalR (https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr) and @types/signalr (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/signalr).

My import looks like this:

```
import * as signalR from 'signalr';
```

The problem is I got an error: "File '... /node_modules/@types/signalr/index.d.ts' is not a module.

Not sure what to do about this. It's only with signalR library I have this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply using `import 'signalr'` worked.

Comment: How did you use in methods?

Comment: It was long time ago, I just looked, now I have:
`import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';`